# Prevent href because of taphold dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, tap

I dynamically generate a list like this:

```
$("#list").append("<li><a class='touchable' id=" + results.rows.item(i).id + " href='#list' onclick='showDetailsList(" +  results.rows.item(i).id + ");'>" + results.rows.item(i).name + "</a></li>");
```

As you can see I add the class 'touchable' to the a link. Now I have:

```
$(document).on("taphold",".touchable",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).simpledialog2({
        mode:"blank",
        headerText:"Image Options",
        showModal:false,
        forceInput:true,
        headerClose:true,
        blankContent:"<ul data-role='listview'><li><a href=''>Send to Facebook</a></li><li><a href=''>Send to Twitter</a></li><li><a href=''>Send to Cat</a></li></ul>"
    });
});
```

I added 'e.preventDefault()'. But when I tap the link for some seconds the dialog shows but when I release the click it automatically jumps to the other page.

I want to have the option to make a choice in the dialog and don't go to the other page. How can I do this?

Comment: may be event is bubbling to parent...add `e.stopPropagation()` too.

Comment: Added it to my beginpost and code but still no result

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for that so we can have better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that when you release the click, the `click` event will fire on the link and you will jump to the other page. What you could do is to bind a `click` event handler to `$(this)` inside the taphold event handler which will prevent the event bubbling.

So something like this

```
$(this).one("click", function(e) { // one to only handle one (the next) click event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

inside your taphold handler *should* work.